# CSS variable is not defined

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I'm developing a wordpress plugin, initially for personal use.

The plugin has a stylesheet, which relies on another stylesheet installed by another plugin defined along these lines

```
@import url('/automaticcss-plugin/scss/automatic.css');


.swatch{
    width:75px;
    height:75px; 
  }
.swatch-primary-ultra-light{
  background: var(--primary-ultra-light);
}
```

I have been developing this in VS code and the intellisense therein suggests that the url for the imports statement is valid and also that the var(--primary-ultra-light) is valid.  That variable is defined in the root of the imported css stylesheet.

When I try and run my plugin though the background colour that I'm expecting is not there and when I use the Inspect tooling my var(--primary-ultra-light) is listed as being undefined.

Wordpress plugin development is a new field to me and I'm not entirely sure what I might have got wrong here.  I'm assuming it's the url, despite the fact that vs code certaily led me to assume that it was correct.

Comment: Make sure the /automaticcss-plugin/scss/automatic.css is actually getting loaded. Generally it looks like this - http://testing.local/wp-content/plugins/formidable/css/formidableforms.css so if it is loaded via another plugin already, you are also increasing the overhead of the site as import is pulling it into your file as well.

Comment: @MarkTruitt  You're absolutely correct it wasn't being loaded.  I'm aware that there will be an overhead, but given that the plugin is designed to work only on the backend I'm not as concerned about that.  It turns out that my imports statement should have read '@import url('http://localhost:81/vtl/wp-content/plugins/automaticcss-plugin/scss/automatic.css'); '  Would you know how I could make that more generic.  The stylesheet I need will always be in the plugins directory but obviously what comes before that could change.

Comment: Figured but wanted to make sure about the extra CSS. You could try just /wp-content or ../wp-content. If you are using gulp, webpack etc you could compile their SCSS into yours as well.